# Typeclass instance for type synonym

Tags: haskell, types

Afraid that I've grossly misunderstood types in Haskell. I'll get into it. Say I have a type defined so:

```
type Vector = [Num a]
```

So I'm using a typeclass in the definition of the synonym. Then if I want to add it to another typeclass, say Eq, maybe I would do something like so:

```
instance Eq Vector a where
  [] == [] = True
  [_]== [] = False
  [] == [_] = False
  (a : u) == (b : v) = (a == b) && (u == v)
```

But when I do this, GHC gives a

> parse error on input '['

It's referring to the first left bracket in the line `[_]== [] = False`.

Is this caused by an issue with my type definition?

Comment: Do you have a typo or something missing from what you copied into the question? I don't believe you have a `type Vector = [Num a]` because the type variable `a` doesn't exist. If you did, what is the `Num` type? It can't be the [`Num`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t:Num) class from base, since that's a constraint, not a type.

Comment: If `Vector a` is a type snonymn defined as being a list `[F a]` why are you trying to write an `Eq` instance for it? There's already an `Eq` instance for `Eq a => Eq [a]`.

Comment: @Cirdec, I thought as much about 'constraint, not a type' but to my surprise GHCi was happy with `type Vector a = [Num a]` (and every other known type class in place of `Num`).

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy My 7.10 GHCi objects to `type Vector a = [Num a]` with the error `Expected kind '*', but 'Num a' has kind 'Constraint'`, unsurprisingly even with `PolyKinds` and `DataKinds` enabled.

Comment: @Cirdec, Mine is 7.6.3. Looks like a bug that's been fixed.

Comment: Btw, If I remember correctly, one cannot define an instance of type class on a type synonym.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy Using `FlexibleInstances` I believe it's possible. However it shouldn't overlap with existing instances (in this case it would overlap). E.g. `class A a;instance A String` compiles when using that extension.

Comment: I get a `not in scope: type variable 'a' ` on GHC 7.8.3.

Comment: As has been said, there are several errors in this code. But the `parse error on input '['` is not related to types (types are only checked once *everything* already parses). It's most likely due to an indentation problem, which we cannot see in your paste here.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with this code, preventing it from being compiled.  I think you mean that `Vector` is parameterized by the type `a` that it contains:

`type Vector a = [a]`

I've dropped the `Num` constraint because it isn't needed for the rest of the example; I'll pick it up at the end.

There's already an `Eq` instance for lists, so this is a bit of a dead end.  One way forward is to switch to a newtype:

`newtype Vector a = Vector [a]`

Unlike a type synonym declared with `type`, Haskell sees a `newtype` as a completely different type.  A `Vector` is not a list, so we can define whatever type class instances we want.

Our `Eq` instance gets a little longer, because we have to write the `Vector` constructor each time.  I added parentheses around `Vector a` in the first line.

The only other change we need to make is adding the `Eq a` constraint before the instance.  In the last line of the definition, we compare the first element of the two `Vectors`.  This only makes sense if the type `a` is an instance of `Eq`.

```
instance Eq a => Eq (Vector a) where
  Vector [] == Vector [] = True
  Vector [_] == Vector [] = False
  Vector [] == Vector [_] = False
  Vector (a : u) == Vector (b : v) = (a == b) && (Vector u == Vector v)
```

This compiles.  You could add a `Num` constraint, insisting that no one may construct a `Vector a` unless `a` is `Num`, or that `Vector a` is only `Eq` if `a` is `Num`.  If this is something you want to do, I can add an example.

Comment: Don't add examples of bad code. Such restrictions went out years ago.

Comment: @dfeuer, was that a criticism of the examples I gave, or just a response to my last paragraph?  If the latter - yes, I left it out because it's a bad practice.

Comment: @bergey sorry to bring up an old post, but I am interested in learning Haskell. In order to make sure that a `Vector` can only contains types that are instances of `Num`, would a quantified type do? `data Vector a = forall a . Num a => Vector [a]`? Or is there a more "direct" way of doing this?

Comment: @StevenL. I think you will do better making a new question for your post.  You'll get better answers if you explain the wider context of what you're trying to do.  What do you want to permit and forbid?  The type you propose doesn't do what you want, but I don't know what else to suggest without knowing *what* you want.